# Error while using static field

Tags: java, android, static, field

I already make some search on the forum and on google about initializing and using a static field. But I can't fix it alone so here is the simplified code:

```
...
import android.graphics.Canvas;
...

public class MyActivity extends Activity{

...
public static Canvas myCanvas = new Canvas();
public static float myMaxX;
public static float myMaxY;
...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...
    myMaxX = myCanvas.getWidth(); // <=== Error, the app crashes right there
    myMaxY = myCanvas.getHeight();
    ... 
    ...

    }
...
}
```

Did I miss something ?

Comment: Can you post the exception along with its stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes!

You need to create a bitmap first:

```
int w = WIDTH_PX, h = HEIGHT_PX;

BitmapConfig conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888; // see other conf types
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, conf); // this creates a MUTABLE bitmap
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);

// ready to draw on that bitmap through that canvas
```

But creating a static Canvas reeks of code smell.  I don't know what you're trying to do with it, but I don't think anything good will come of it.  You may find you run in to loads of issues around concurrent read/write violations if you're sharing this canvas between multiple threads.

Comment: Thanks, it worked (even though I still don't really get it)
The reason of static canvas is that, I want to draw a lot of bitmaps, and those bitmaps are inside other classes. I want them to use the same Canvas property, so creating and initializing many copies of the same Canvas will consume lot of time. That's why it's better to create a static one, it uses much less memory space, and much less time.

Comment: have a look at the docs - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html - "The Canvas class holds the "draw" calls. To draw something, you need 4 basic components: A Bitmap to hold the pixels, a Canvas to host the draw calls (writing into the bitmap), a drawing primitive (e.g. Rect, Path, text, Bitmap), and a paint (to describe the colors and styles for the drawing)."

Answer (score -1):

the variable myCanvas may not have a value at that point. So you must check for a null value.

```
 myMaxX = (myCanvas != null)?myCanvas.getWidth():0; 
                // <=== check for null
```

Comment: Why would myCanvas not have a value yet? It is initialized as a static field.

Comment: I did a verification  
    `if (myCanvas == null){  
        Log.w("myApp", "myCanvas is null");  
        myMaxX = 0;  
    }  
    else {  
        Log.w("myApp", "no it isn't");  
        myMaxX = myCanvas.getWidth();  
    }`  

The debug shows that it isn't null.

Comment: @dj8, it is static, but not final, isn't it possible to be cleared somewhere else? In any case, it is a good practice to check for null, rather than leaving it to an assumption. I am offended you down voted me.

Comment: @mhfff32, so what is actually "crashing", would you care to post the actual exception or the stack trace?